# iPhone 4 incorrect screen size?

Tags: iphone, screen, uidevice

Could someone tell me why the following code would return `Screen Size: 320.000000, 480.000000` on the iPhone 4?

```
 CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
 NSLog(@"Screen Size: %f, %f", screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That method returns a size in *Points*, not Pixels. If you are a registered apple developer, I would suggest watching the WWDC (new) video on designing for the Retina display. It has a load of really useful information.

UIKit uses points, however OpenGL uses pixels. UIViews now have a  [contentScaleFactor property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW130), which will be 2 on iPhone 4, and 1 on everything else so far...