# What is the size of iphone4 device

Tags: css

I am writing the css for a mobile web app.
As I am realizing the width of the iphone4 screen supposed to be 640px. 
The results I am getting from the browser though indicating that the screen is 
320px. If for instance I use a div with 160px it's occupy the half screen.
My question is for a mobile app which are the dimensions I have to design for ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668341/media-query-ipad-vs-iphone4

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone 4 incorrect screen size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125480/iphone-4-incorrect-screen-size)

Comment: @katzenhut - While I suspect it's a duplicate of an existing question, your linked one is not that question. This question is a matter of the disparity between hardware pixels and CSS pixels. Your linked question appears to be and Obj-C question and is talking about *points* vs *pixels*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't design for dimensions.**

You'll drive yourself insane, if you do. Why?

Which one's larger - an iPad or a desktop monitor? Probably not the one you're expecting. The latest iPad clocks in at [2048x1536](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/), which is arguably larger than many desktop monitors.

Additionally, devices are known to "lie" about their resolution, as you're seeing now. This has to do with pixel density and the difference between device pixels (historically, a physical piece in the display) and CSS pixels (a unit of measurement).

Also, depending on what you're changing with the media queries, you might have unexpected results. The Kindle Touch, for example, reports the same resolution as the same-generation iPad, *but* its base font size is 20px, instead of the usual 16px. This can spell disaster for your design, especially if you're using em-based fonts. Then, there's also the fact that **mobile devices aren't the only non-desktop screens out there.** What about projectors? They generally run at a resolution of 1024x768 or higher, but they're often better suited to using the "mobile" layout, due to how far the viewing distance is. Running in "desktop" layout, you often end up with extremely small text and/or extremely long lines. Neither of which are good.

Finally, *device size* does not always equal *viewport size*. This is especially the case with any device that can un-maximize the window - including not just desktops, but any device running Windows 8 (it has a sort of side-by-side mode).

So what do you do? Design your breakpoints, instead, based on your content. [Check out em-based media queries](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/), which use a relative measurement, instead of fixed widths, and, of course, make sure your design is flexible-width by nature.

If you're still intent on using pixels, though, the iPhone is 320x480 for the purposes of CSS. It's listed as 640x960 because the pixel density is greater than 72dpi (it's 144dpi, or 2x density). In this case, 1 CSS pixel equals 4 hardware pixels (2 across, 2 down). However, also beware that that's not always the case. Many Android devices are 1.5x pixel density, and the trend is going toward even higher densities. This doesn't affect your CSS quite as much (except for the disparity between listed resolutions and functional CSS resolutions), but it does affect your images.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone4 has 640 *physical* pixels of width, but iOS Safari doesn't use physical pixels when evaluating stylesheets.  Instead, iOS Safari presents as if it were 320 px wide, so as to be closer to previous iPhone widths.

If you really need to access the high-resolutions screens separately, you can use: `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio`.  Remember that iOS is not the only high-resolution device out there.  See more about device pixel ratio at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio.

Answer (score -1):

use this tool **(screenfly)** it's awsome https://quirktools.com/screenfly/